# best practice for getting Map value from arguments in a method in java?

Tags: java, dictionary

I want to pass a Map that contains key and value that is Listview,
which of this 2 method is a good practice in getting the map from arguments

```
Map<String, List<String>> mMap;

public static void add(Map<String, List<String> map) {
    mMap = map; // direct get and assign to map object
}

public static void add(Map<String, List<String> map) {
    try {
        //Copies all of the mappings from the specified map to this map 
        mMap.putAll(map); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

in the 2 method which is the right way in assigning the value of map argument to our new Map object?

Comment: 1st method will replace old values, if you want so..

Comment: thank you guyz for all the info you give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should consider that when you pass an object to a method, if you change it inside that method, the changes will affect the parameter, So it's all around this. If you **want** to change the parameter (map here) inside the method you **should** use the first way, and if (probably in most cases) you don't want to your parameter (map) changes inside the method and just want to use the values inside it you **should** use the second method.

BTW, I use `should` for the options you provided, albeit there are other ways but the philosophy is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your first method is not an add, but a replace, so the second method is the preferable one. But the second one will fail, because your object is not initialized and therefore null.

Answer (score 0):

First of all static things are not the best at all in use(performance - might be low).
Second method is better.

```
public void add(Map<String, List<String> map) 
{
    try 
    {
         //Copies all of the mappings from the specified map to this map 
         mMap.putAll(map); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is considered a bad practice to assign collections directly. The reason is that if you do so probably somebody can change the map content outside your class that does not have any chance to know about the change. So, your class's functionality may become inconsistent or even throw exception because map can be changed between or event during its processing by your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this implementation: [Guava Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Guava is already standard library for broad variety of projects.